# Custom error in asp.net mvc4 - Getting called with every request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently have Custom errors setup in a asp.net mvc4 web application in web.config

```
> <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Errors"> </customErrors>



  public class ErrorsController : Controller
    {
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

      return Content("Unexpected Error - Please contact Administrator");
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the Action Index gets called on every call even though there is no error

Would help if anybody can clarify this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure why the Action Index gets called on every call even though there is no error

How do you know that there is no error? Maybe the browser is attempting to GET `/favicon.ico` which you forgot to include in your application and the server is throwing a 404 Not Found exception. Or maybe a missing javascript, css or image? Of course that's only one of the gazillions possible reasons why your Error action might be called.

Once inside the Error action you could always inspect the value of the `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to know more about the exact request sent by the client.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your `RouteConfig`.  If you have a specific route for the error that is being matched before the others than you would keep getting the error.